# Design view of Android studio is empty

Tags: java, android, android-studio, layout, compile-time

I created a new project, and the design view is empty, anything I dragged into `activity_main.xml` is not visible.

[image]

Comment: add dependency of gradle please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please Fallow these steps

```
1- Go to your res folder and inside res folder.
        2-Go to values.
        3-Go to style.xml
        4-change  <!-- Base application theme. -->
            <stylename="AppTheme"parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        to <stylename="AppTheme"parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to have a similar problem. Changing to a lower version of appcompat has solved this for me.

Go to build.gradle, under dependencies change

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

Then make sure to sync the project again. Good luck and happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

According to [CoordinatorLayout is not visible in Design view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51441114/coordinatorlayout-is-not-visible-in-design-view), change versions of all android libraries to `28.0.0-alpha1`:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
```